# ESXi 4.0 Licensing Limits

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-esxi

From what I understand, the software is free and you just need to register to remove the 60-day limitation. Does this mean I have to register every time I install ESXi on a new machine? Or can I use the same key for different ESXi 4.0 installations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may have changed since but the last time I registered for keys I was prompted to enter a quantity, so you should be able to obtain what you need without having to repeat the registration.

Answer (score 2):

As John mentioned, you can obtain a key for a certain number of activations. Each time you install a new ESXi machine, you activate with the same key.

Comment: You are on your honour to tell them how many you're using; even if there's no specific limit.

Comment: Sure. I just request a number of activations equivalent to the number of physical hosts on my network. I will probably convert them all eventually, anyway.